# Add datetimepicker to StatusStrip control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, statusstrip

I want to add a datetimepicker to a StatusStrip control to show today's date, so is there any way to add other controls than the label and progress bar to the StatusStrip control??

Comment: Easiest way (but not so attractive because of unmatched style) is to add a `ToolStripItem` derived class, in your case `ToolStripControlHost` (where you'll place a `DateTimePicker` control). I'd avoid this in favor of a `ToolStripDropDownButton` that will display a list of `ToolStripDropDownItem`, there you can place your `ToolStripControlHost` (still not so nice but at least visible only on-demand).

Comment: execuse me can you explain more because i didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check this from :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/edbd92be-76ee-49b1-b7c6-f6522992a14a/using-toolstripcontrolhost-with-datetimepicker

```
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ToolStrip)]
public class ToolStripDateTimePicker : ToolStripControlHost
{
    private FlowLayoutPanel controlPanel;
    private DateTimePicker picker = new DateTimePicker();

    public ToolStripDateTimePicker()
        : base(new FlowLayoutPanel())
    {
        controlPanel = (FlowLayoutPanel)base.Control;
        controlPanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        AutoSize = false;

        controlPanel.Controls.Add(picker);
    }

    public DateTime Value
    {
        get { return this.picker.Value; }
        set { this.picker.Value = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnSubscribeControlEvents(Control control)
    {
        base.OnSubscribeControlEvents(control);
    }

    protected override void OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(Control control)
    {
        base.OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(control);
    }
}
```